# I need to loop through an “if, elif” statement until a the user’s input is a zero…

Tags: python, if-statement

I am creating a program that prints a line of text based upon the value the user enters. I am going to use an “if, elif” statement.

Example: if age (what the user entered) <= 1:
Print(“this is an infant”)

I also need the entire thing, the input and the if elif statement, to repeat until the user enters a zero…I’m totally stumped on getting the statement to loop *without* having the text repeat continuously.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
print("Enter your age")
while True:
    age = int(input())
    if age <= 1:
        print("Infant")
```

Kindly adjust this code with yours.
I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!!